# Using SED to add values after the 5th field of a CSV file that is also an IP Address

Tags: csv, sed

I have a CSV file that I'm working to manipulate using sed. What I'm doing is inserting the current YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS into the 5th field after the IP Address. As you can see below, each value is enclosed by double quotes and each CSV column is separated by a comma.

```
"12345","","","None","192.168.2.1","qqq","000"
"67890","ABC-1234-5678","9.9","Low","192.168.2.1","qqq","000"
```

Using the command: `sed 'N;s/","/","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","/5' FILENAME`
I am adding in the date after the 5th field. Normally this works, but often
certain values in the CSV file mess up this count that would insert the date into the 5th field. To remedy this issue, how can I not only add the date after the 5th field, but also make sure the 5th field is an IP Address?

The final output should be:

```
"12345","","","None","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
"67890","ABC-1234-5678","9.9","Low","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
```

Please respond with how this is done using SED and not AWK. And how I can make sure the 5th field is also an IP Address before the date is added in?

Comment: Why can't you use awk? It would be much better suited.

Comment: What should happen on lines where $5 is not an IP address?

Comment: How clean is your CSV file?  Are there ever fields without the double quotes around them?  Are there ever fields with `"…""…"` to indicate a double quote embedded in the string?  Are there ever fields with commas in between the quotes (`"this,that"`)?  It's not dreadfully critical, but does the value of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` need to be set from a variable (e.g. the output of `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` is captured and substituted into the `sed` command)?

Comment: The CSV file isn't very clean. There are random Double quotes that will appear within the data values. But a constant is the 5th field will always be an IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer currently assumes that the CSV file is beautifully consistent and simple (as in the sample data), so that:

- Fields always have double quotes around them.
- There are never fields like `"…""…"` to indicate a double quote embedded in the string.
- There are never fields with commas in between the quotes (`"this,that"`).

Given those pre-requisites, this `sed` script does the job:

```
sed 's/^\("[^"]*",\)\{4\}"\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}",/&"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",/'
```

Let's split that search pattern into pieces:

- `^\("[^"]*",\)\{4\}`

  Match start of line followed by: 4 repeats of a double quote, a sequence of zero or more non-double-quotes, a double quote and a comma.

  In other words, this identifies the first four fields.
- `"\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}`

  Match a double quote, then 3 repeats of 1-3 decimal digits followed by a dot — the first three triplets of an IPv4 dotted-decimal address.
- `[0-9]\{1,3\}",`

  Match 1-3 decimal digits followed by a double quote and a comma — the last triplet of an IPv4 dotted-decimal address plus the end of a field.

Clearly, for each idiosyncrasy of CSV files that you also need to deal with, you have to modify the regular expressions.  That's not trivial.

Using extended regular expressions (enabled by `-E` on both GNU and BSD `sed`), you could write:

```
sed -E 's/^("(([^"]*"")*[^"]*)",){4}"([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}",/&"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",/'
```

The pattern to recognize the first 4 fields is more complex than before.  It matches 4 repeats of: double quote, zero or more occurrences of { zero or more non-double-quotes followed by two double quotes } followed by zero or more non-double-quotes followed by a double quote and a comma.

You can also write that in classic `sed` (basic regular expressions) with a liberal sprinkling of backslashes:

```
sed 's/^\("\(\([^"]*""\)*[^"]*\)",\)\{4\}"\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}",/&"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",/'
```

Given the data file:

```
"12345","","","None","192.168.2.1","qqq","000"
"67890","ABC-1234-5678","9.9","Low","192.168.2.1","qqq","000"
"23456","Quaternions","2.3","Pisces","Heredotus","qqq","000"
"34567","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quotes"" quoth he","192.168.99.37","zzz","011"
"45678","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quote me"",""or not""","192.168.99.37","zzz","011"
```

The first script shown produces the output:

```
"12345","","","None","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
"67890","ABC-1234-5678","9.9","Low","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
"23456","Quaternions","2.3","Pisces","Heredotus","qqq","000"
"34567","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quotes"" quoth he","192.168.99.37","zzz","011"
"45678","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quote me"",""or not""","192.168.99.37","zzz","011"
```

The first two lines are correctly mapped; the third is correctly unchanged, but the last two should have been mapped and were not.

The second and third commands produce:

```
"12345","","","None","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
"67890","ABC-1234-5678","9.9","Low","192.168.2.1","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","qqq","000"
"23456","Quaternions","2.3","Pisces","Heredotus","qqq","000"
"34567","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quotes"" quoth he","192.168.99.37","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","zzz","011"
"45678","Commas, oh commas!","3.14159","""Quote me"",""or not""","192.168.99.37","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS","zzz","011"
```

Note that Heredotus is not modified (correctly), and the last two lines get the date string added after the IP address (also correctly).

Those last regular expressions are not for the faint-of-heart.

Clearly, if you want to insist that the IP addresses only match numbers in the range 0..255 in each component, with no leading 0, then you have to beef up the IP address matching portion of the regular expression.  It can be done; it is not pretty.  It is easiest to do it with extended regular expressions:

```
([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

You'd use that unit in place of each `[0-9]{3}` unit in the regexes shown before.

Note that this still does not attempt to deal with fields not surrounded by double quotes.

It also does not determine the value to substitute from the `date` command.  That is doable with (if not elementary then) routine shell scripting carefully managing quotes:

```
dt=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sed -E 's/^("(([^"]*"")*[^"]*)",){4}"([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}",/&"'"$dt"'",/'
```

The `'…"'"$dt"'",/'` sequence is part of what starts out as a single-quoted string.  The first double quote is simple data in the string; the next single quote ends the quoting, the `"$dt"` interpolates the value from `date` inside shell double quotes (so the space doesn't cause any trouble), then the single quote resumes the single-quoted notation, adding another double quote, a comma and a slash before the string (argument to `sed`) is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk -vdate1=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") -vdate2=$(date +"%H:%M:%S") -F, '$5 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/{$5=$5 FS date1 " " date2} 1' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Also if you want to edit the same Input_file you could take above command's output into a temp file and later rename(mv command) to the same Input_file

Adding one-liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -vdate1=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") -vdate2=$(date +"%H:%M:%S") -F, '
            $5 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/{
            $5=$5 FS date1 " " date2
                                                }
            1
    '  OFS=,    Input_file
```

Comment: While I agree that awk would be a good tool to do this, it kind of ignores the request to use sed and not awk.